# Command not found mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I am trying to start deploying a rails app with `mina` gem only I can not seem to get it initialized.

As you can see here, I am not doing anything out of the ordinary, I have added `mina` to my gem list, it installs fine, but the executable is not found.

```
➜  trackitall git:(master) ✗ bin/bundle install
40 other gems
Using mina 0.3.4
Bundle complete! 41 Gemfile dependencies, 143 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
➜  trackitall git:(master) ✗ mina init
zsh: command not found: mina
➜  trackitall git:(master) ✗
```

I am using rbenv with `ruby 2.1.5` for this project on macOS 10.10.3. Also there is no `mina` shim in the `~/.rbenv/shims` folder. As far as I understand, rbenv here should be all the executables for your specific ruby env.

Answer (score 2):

I was using rbenv and had the same problem where mina was not being found. All I had to do was:

```
rbenv rehash
```

and then

```
mina init
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, noobie mistake.

The problem was that mina is not in the environment. So you can either run

- `bundle execute mina` for executing mina in your current gem environment
- or run `rbenv rehash` and then `mina` should be available in your path

Comment: alterd my answer to make it more useful :)